# How many hexagonal paths?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a hexagonal tiling, borrowed from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling).

[image: hexagonal tiling]

I start in any hexagon on the left hand side. I end at any hexagon on the right hand side. I can only travel to the right, not up, down or backwards.

> **In how many ways can this be done?**

Comment: bonus question: if the grid is extended to $2k$ columns in total, what is the sum of the $2k^{th}$ column?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> 74280

Method

> Every cell in the first column can be reached 1 way.
>  Other cells can be reached as many different ways, as the sum of their two left neighbours, giving:
>  [image]
>  The sum of the numbers in the last column is the answer to the question posted.

Comment: I think I might give this the tick for the presentation aspect and the right answer. The bottom row is [A001700](https://oeis.org/A001700).

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, actually it isn't. The sequences start to differ from the 2*12=24th column, when the diagonal hits the top/bottom.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer might be:

> **73392**?

Reasoning:

> Well, I made a Pascal's Triangle-like chart with alternating 11 and 12 columns, and 14 rows, where each number was the sum of the two numbers northwest and northeast of it. I added all of the numbers on the bottom row. It's quite likely I messed up some addition, though.

Comment: The method seems to be correct, but I'm afraid your calculation is flawed indeed.

Comment: @elias yeah, I thought that would be the case.

Comment: Also I'm sure you meant northwest and **southwest** instead of northeast.

Comment: @elias I did the chart vertically instead of horizontally like the question asked (same result, and easier for me to draw), so for me it was northeast. I see how this could cause a bit of confusion though.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> $83,746$

Method:

> Consider the first 2 columns of this diagram. There are 11 starting positions, and 12 destinations. Each starting position can go to one of 2 destinations, so the number of possible paths is equal to $11 \cdot 2 = 22$.
>
>  Now, consider columns 2 and 3 of the diagram. There are 12 starting positions, and 11 destinations. 10 of the starting positions have 2 possible destinations, and 2 of them only have 1 possible destination (the top and bottom ones). This means the total number of possible paths is $(10 \cdot 2) + 2 = 22$.
>
>  If we now consider the first 3 columns, it can be seen that each of the internal starting positions has 4 possible paths, and the top and bottom ones have 3. Therefore, in total, there are $(9 \cdot 4) + (2 \cdot 3) = 36 + 6 = 42$ possible paths across the first 3 columns.
>
>  In the initial consideration, the inner hexes were each finished on twice, and the outer ones once. Therefore, a second way to work out the number of paths in the third consideration, would be to edit the calculation for consideration 2 to be $((10 \cdot 2) \cdot 2) + (2 \cdot 1) = 40 + 2 = 42$.
>
>  Next, considering the first 4 columns, each of the paths already determined for the first 3, has 2 more possible destinations, so the number of paths would total $42 \cdot 2 = 84$.
>
>  Using these values, I can determine a formula for calculating the number of paths, where n increases by 1 for every repeating pair of columns.
>  $\Sigma_n = ((\Sigma_{n-1} - n) \cdot 4) + 2n$
>
>  Therefore, we can step through this calculation to determine the results of:
>  $\Sigma_1 = 22$
>  $\Sigma_2 = 84$
>  $\Sigma_3 = 330$
>  $\Sigma_4 = 1312$
>  $\Sigma_5 = 5238$
>  $\Sigma_6 = 20,940$
>  $\Sigma_7 = 83,746$
>  As there are 7 pairs of columns in the above image, (if my formula is correct), I believe there to be $83,746$ possible paths.

Bonus Question:

> $\Sigma_n = ((\Sigma_{n-1} - n) \cdot 4) + 2n$  where $n=2k$

Comment: I'm pretty sure @NudgeNudge 's earlier answer of 90112 is an upper bound for the answer.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu you're right, I think I had an unnecessary factor of n